# SQL Server Express - Remote Connection continues to fail

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-express, named-pipes, sql-server-2008-express, remote-connection

I have been unable to configure my SQL Server 2008 Express to allow remote connections.  I followed the instructions from this guide: http://www.linglom.com/2009/03/28/enable-remote-connection-on-sql-server-2008-express/ .

I am still getting the following error:

> Cannot connect to 00.00.00.000
>
> Additional information:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.  Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>
> (Provider: Named Pipes Provider, error 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) ( Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 3)

I also configured the firewall as defined in http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/ . As a test I even turned off the firewall, but nothing changed, so it is not the issue.

**Update** under server name, it only says the IP address. Do I need something more?

Comment: How are you trying to connect to the remote instance - SSMS, from code, something else...?  The "Named Pipes Provider" part of the error message makes me think you're using the wrong means of connecting...

Comment: @Will A, I'm using SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Server name` field of Connect to Server, I had `myipaddress`.  I changed it to `myipaddress\SQLEXPRESS` and it works.

In addition, once this was working without the firewall I applied settings as defined in http://www.sevenforums.com/system-security/58817-remote-access-sql-server-express-2008-windows-7-a.html to make the connection work with the firewall turned on.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have sysadmin rights in sql express? It may be that your user account doesn't have the necessary permissions. There is a script on [codeplex](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/addselftosqlsysadmin/) that will add you logged on account as a sysadmin.